Is there a requirement for citizens to report crimes in Spain?
I am curious how the Spanish legal system covers the scenario below.
When a civilian in Spain stumbles upon somebody committing a criminal offence, are they obliged to report what they have seen to the police? For the sake of this scenario, you can assume the actions can result in at least 1-year imprisonment.
For any answers, do include any relevant parts of the Spanish Penal Code, and other relevant legislation for criminal law.
The term I am searching for is perhaps "mandatory reporting" but it feels more inclined towards people in certain professions, for example a Bank Manager having to report that an account is being used for money laundering. My question is about civilians only...
The keyword might be: misprision?

Misprision would indeed be an excellent English translation, but few translators from Spanish to English, even specialized legal translators, would know that word as it is somewhat archaic even in legal English.


When a civilian in Spain stumbles upon somebody committing a criminal
offence, are they obliged to report what they have seen to the police?

Yes. But the penalty is nominal and almost never enforced against a random civilian who witnesses a crime.

Articles 259 and 262 of the Criminal Procedure Law impose a general
obligation on individuals who witness an offence (or know of the
existence of an offence through their professional activity) to report
misconduct; however, the consequences set out for the infringement of
this obligation are purely symbolic (a maximum fine of less than €2)
and the obligation is never enforced in practice. Only civil servants
have an actual obligation to report misconduct of which they become
aware in the course of their professional activities. If they fail to
do so, they may be held criminally liable and face a penalty of
professional debarment.
Nevertheless, reporting misconduct is mandatory pursuant to anti-money
laundering and countering the financing of terrorism (Anti-Money
Laundering Law, Article 63 read with Article 18) and market abuse
regulations (Regulation (EU) No. 596/2014, Article 16.2).
Law 2/2023 (going far beyond Directive (EU) 2019/1937 as to the
creation of a whistleblower protection regime) has introduced an
entirely new obligation for companies to report to the Public
Prosecutor’s Office any potential criminal offences arising from
whistleblower reports received through their internal whistleblowing
channels (Article 9.2.j)). Although its practical scope is as yet
untested, practitioners and scholars have warned that this obligation
may conflict with a company’s right against self-incrimination
(Spanish Constitution, Article 24.2) when the potential criminal
offence at stake triggers corporate criminal liability.

(Source)
As an aside, in the U.S., unlike Spain, while individuals have a privilege against self-incrimination, corporations do not.
The Criminal Procedure Law of Spain referenced above is available as of the year 2015 at this site belonging to the World Intellectual Property Organization (a U.N. affiliate). Article 259 states (in Spanish)

Artículo 259.
El que presenciare la perpetración de cualquier delito público está
obligado a ponerlo inmediatamente en conocimiento del Juez de
instrucción, de paz, comarcal o municipal o funcionario fiscal más
próximo al sitio en que se hallare, bajo la multa de 25 a 250 pesetas
. . .
Artículo 262.
Los que por razón de sus cargos, profesiones u oficios tuvieren
noticia de algún delito público, estarán obligados a denunciarlo
inmediatamente al Ministerio fiscal, al Tribunal competente, al Juez
de instrucción y, en su defecto, al municipal o al funcionario de
policía más próximo al sitio si se tratare de un delito flagrante. Los
que no cumpliesen esta obligación incurrirán en la multa señalada en
el artículo 259, que se impondrá disciplinariamente.
Si la omisión en dar parte fuere de un Profesor en Medicina, Cirugía o
Farmacia y tuviese relación con el ejercicio de sus actividades
profesionales, la multa no podrá ser inferior a 125 pesetas ni
superior a 250.
Si el que hubiese incurrido en la omisión fuere empleado público, se
pondrá además en conocimiento de su superior inmediato para los
efectos a que hubiere lugar en el orden administrativo.
Lo dispuesto en este artículo se entiende cuando la omisión no
produjere responsabilidad con arreglo a las Leyes.

Google translates these articles from Spanish to English, not flawlessly, but well enough to convey the gist of the language, as follows:

Article 259.
Anyone who witnesses the perpetration of any public crime is obliged
to immediately report it to the investigating judge, peace judge,
regional or municipal judge or fiscal official closest to the place
where he or she is located, subject to a fine of 25 to 250 pesetas.
. . .
Article 262.
Those who, due to their positions, professions or trades, become aware
of any public crime, will be obliged to immediately report it to the
Public Prosecutor's Office, the competent Court, the Investigating
Judge and, failing that, to the nearest municipal or police officer.
to the site if it is a flagrant crime. Those who do not comply with
this obligation will incur the fine indicated in article 259, which
will be imposed disciplinaryly.
If the omission to report is by a Professor in Medicine, Surgery or
Pharmacy and is related to the exercise of their professional
activities, the fine may not be less than 125 pesetas nor more than
250.
If the person who committed the omission is a public employee, his or
her immediate superior will also be informed for the purposes that may
apply in the administrative order.
The provisions of this article are understood when the omission does
not produce liability in accordance with the Laws.

